# How to call elements in product for loop

Tags: python-3.x, product, python-itertools

I would like to replace this nested loop with `itertools.product`:

```
seasons = ['long', 'short']
weathers = ['dry', 'wet', 'sunny']

for season in seasons:
    for weather in weathers:
        output = "S= " + season + "&" + "W= " + weather
        print(output)
```

**Output**

```
S= long&W= dry
S= long&W= wet
S= long&W= sunny
S= short&W= dry
S= short&W= wet
S= short&W= sunny
```

I know I can print all elements using this:

```
mylist = list([seasons, weathers])
for element in itertools.product(*mylist):
    print(element)
```

But how can I call individual elements within `itertools.product`?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Aren't you printing individual elements in your last example? Maybe you should show a small example of what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I would like to achieve the same output but with the `itertools.product` instead of a nested for loop.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two variables in the for loop (to *unpack* the tuple returned by `product`):

```
from itertools import product

seasons = ['long', 'short']
weathers = ['dry', 'wet', 'sunny']

for season, weather in product(seasons, weathers):
    output = "S= " + season + "&" + "W= " + weather
    print(output)
```

Output:

```
S= long&W= dry
S= long&W= wet
S= long&W= sunny
S= short&W= dry
S= short&W= wet
S= short&W= sunny
```

Comment: Note: This is the way you *should* use `product` in this scenario, and how it's intended to be used. Like a lot of `itertools` module stuff that produces `tuple`s (and like `zip`), it has an optimized fast path for when the `tuple` it returns is unused when the output is requested; by unpacking, you release the `tuple` immediately, so the fast path can be used.

Comment: That should read: "when the *next* output is requested", and of course I only noticed this after the edit grace period expired.